# How to write action links using javascript in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a script that appends some rows to a table. One of the rows has a delete link, and for that I am using a ActionLink, however the id of the element is received via js, and this is nor working:

```
 $("#Table").last().append('<tr><td><a href=\"<%:Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteElementFromSet", new {id=%>Id<%})%>">Delete</a></td><td>'+Id+'</td></tr>');
```

where Id is a javascript variable that gets its value from the value of a dropdownlist.

Is there a way to use ActionLink like this? or do I have to write down the path manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the id is known only at the client side you will need to construct the proper url. This being said never mix C# and javascript. Here's how you might proceed:

Start by declaring a global variable that will hold the delete link without the id part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var deleteUrl = '<%: Url.Action("DeleteElementFromSet") %>';
</script>
```

and then in a **separate** javascript file:

```
$('#Table').last().append(
    $(document.createElement('tr'))
        .append($(document.createElement('td'))
            .append($(document.createElement('a'))
                .attr('href', deleteUrl + '/' + Id)
                .text('Delete')
            )
        )
        .append($(document.createElement('td'))
            .text(Id)
        )
);
```

Notice that you should use `Url.Action` instead of `Html.ActionLink` because you already have the anchor manually generated.

Remark: avoid using GET verbs for deleting. You might have bad surprises. Use proper verb (or at least POST) when modifying state on the server such as deleting.

Comment: +1 for Url.Action and making it a fixed url / that's modified when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you have an action link helper in MVC.   Create a helper in JavaScript where you provide an action, controller, and id to create a link.

Comment: He doesn't have the Id. How do you pass a javascript variable to an HTML helper?

Comment: Maybe I wasnt Clear, but he has the ID in javascript and he needs a function simular to the ActionLink Helper in .NET.   Basically I am saying create a Javascript function that mimics the ActionLink Helper In .NET

Comment: might not be the way to go since the routes might change

Answer (score 0):

You have to write down the path manually. That's because the C# is evaluated at compile time, and you are writing it to the document at runtime.

A better option is to separate HTML and Javascript completely. Put your HTML in a hidden `div` in your view, then copy its contents to wherever you want using javascript. This way you will still be able to use C# to create the action links.

Separating HTML from Javascript is also improves code readability, separates concerns better and expands syntax highlighting. In other words, it's a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor it to make it clearer. Literally, the equivalent is:

```
var deleteUrl = '<%:Url.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteElementFromSet", new {id=%>Id<%})%>';
$("#Table").last()
   .append('<tr><td><a href=\"' + deleteUrl + '">Delete</a></td><td>'+Id+'</td></tr>');
```

**First thing you can note in there is that you open it with `\"` and you close it with `"`.**

I suggest you do the above exercise until the script is clear and the confusing syntax isn't at play.

Above said, in deleteUrl **you are trying to use a client side value on the server**. Remember <%: will be called during the server side render of the view, so an Id you set on the client side doesn't come into play at all in there.

**An option is to use a place holder, like**:

```
var deleteUrl = '<%:Url.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteElementFromSet", new {id=%>Id<%})%>';
deleteUrl = deleteUrl.replace("##id##", Id);
$("#Table").last()
   .append('<tr><td><a href=\"' + deleteUrl + '">Delete</a></td><td>'+Id+'</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
var row = $("#Table").last().append('<tr><td><%:Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteElementFromSet")%>"></td><td>' + Id + '</td></tr>');
row.find('a').attr(Id);
```

This will add the row, then find the link and add the id attribute.

In your code it looked like there was an extra 'a' tag that I removed.

Comment: that's not what the OP's code is trying to do / id is a parameter to the action.

Comment: Right, I realize that now. He must have meant Action, not an ActionLink html helper (which renders an anchor). ActionLink has a HtmlAttributes overload - which is what i thought he was going for.

Comment: Also, in your post you are making the same mistake. ActionLink is not a URL. It is a HTML Anchor tag. Use Url.Action.