# How to comment jQuery code in partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jQuery code in **partial view** as:

```
        //Reset values 
        ResetAllFields();
        HideDiv();
        //Hide buttons
        $('#btn-id').hide();
```

The two lines `//Reset fields` and `//Hide buttons` are successfully commented.
But, even after I comment out the line as:

`//HideDiv();`

and execute it in debugger mode in chrome, pressing F12, the function gets called, i.e. the line is not commented.
I also tried commenting it out as `@* HideDiv() *@` but in vain.

Am I missing something here? Or, is there a different syntax ?

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code; that might help place it in context.

Comment: there are plenty of good answers - select one

Answer (score 0):

You could try this syntax `/*  your javascript here */` but I would recommend you review this thread [JavaScript in partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098198/is-it-ok-to-put-javascript-in-partial-views) and not include javascript in a partial view at all.

Comment: besides what you have tried, and what I suggested there is no other way I know of to comment out JavaScript.  I would recommend attempting to follow the pattern identified in the thread I provided.

Answer (score 0):

`//your javascript here` or `/* your javascript here  */` do work! It seems that you missed the `<script>` tag in your code.

If so, use:

```
@* your javascript here  *@
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
@://HideDiv();
```

**Note the "@:"**