# How to manage JavaScript in an ASP.NET MVC application - separate files vs. inside of Razor View?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working on an ASP .NET Core MVC application. On previous projects, I would put any page-specific JavaScript at the bottom of my View's `.cshtml` file. However, this project has more page-specific JavaScript and some have recommended using separate `.js` files, one per View. I've had trouble finding recommended patterns. One downside of separate `.js` files is that it's harder to inject data from the `ViewModel` or `ViewBag` which are available in `.cshtml`.

**What are best practices for managing JavaScript in ASP .NET MVC apps?**

We are considering the following, where each view would reference its respective `.js` file. But this still has the downside of not being able to access the `ViewModel`, `ViewBag`, and other helpers.

```
[wwwroot]
-  [js]
-    [src]
-      [mycontroller] // controller folders
-        index.js     // view js files
-        about.js
-      [othercontroller]
```

Comment: In general, when I want to pass something to Javascript, I do it using a hidden input or a `data-*` attribute. That allows for a bit more separation of concerns; your javascript doesn't care who or how the field is populated, it's just grabbing a value from an element. As far as your folder hierarchy is concerned that's really up to personal preference, to me that layout looks fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it OK to put JavaScript in Partial Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098198/is-it-ok-to-put-javascript-in-partial-views)