# CheckBoxFor data toggle on change event not working ? Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, toggle

i am trying to use this jquery code for alerting on change if checked true,

```
 $("#NSupport").change(function () {
            var tid = this.id;

            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                alert("inside");
            }
        });
```

here is my check box,

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NSupport, new { data_toggle = "toggle",data_width = "100", data_on = "yes", data_off = "No", data_offstyle = "info" })
```

Can any one has idea why it is not calling jquery function?

BR

EDIT,

I just use this code in which it is alerting "dad" but only on page load,

```
  $('#NSupport').toggle(
            function () {
                $('.check').attr('Checked', 'Checked');
                alert('mom');
            },
            function () {
                $('.check').removeAttr('Checked');
                alert('dad');
            }
        );
```

Comment: jquery script location in a page top or bottom? Is your script inside the document ready? Is there any console error on dev tools of the browser?

Comment: it is at the bottom and there is no error

Comment: Did you try `$(document).on("change", "#NSupport", function() ...` ?

Comment: Note: `.toggle` is synonymous with `.show`/`.hide` - it's not an event that occurs when the checkbox is "toggled" so runs at start, 1st arg is duration and 2nd is oncomplete - so runs at startup because it toggles visibility immediately.  https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Just before your `$("#NSupport").change` add the line `console.log($("#NSupport").length)` - if it's 0/zero at that time then the event has nothing to attach to and you'll need event delegation or call it later

Comment: @freedomn-m it is showing 1 in comsole

Comment: That's a start, can you also do: `console.log($("[id=NSupport]").length)` (should have included that, sorry)

Comment: @freedomn-m it is also showing 1 for this.

Comment: The next step is to try to *recreate* the issue - either here in an SO snippet (preferred) (see [mcve]) or a jsfiddle or just on your page.  Either start with nothing and add components/js so it works then continue adding the rest of your page until it stops working - or removing parts of your page until it works.   Your code *as provided in the question* can *easily* be demonstrated to work fine (https://jsfiddle.net/pn9rhtqe/), so there must be something else in your page/project that's stopping it.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for your help but i really dont understand how to fix it. which part stops it working. i check link its bouncing on my head

Comment: By the way simple check box  calling change function from the same partial view i am using this data toggle

Answer (score 1):

Put the javascript code inside jQuery onready event like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NSupport").change(function () {
        var tid = this.id;

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert("inside");
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: To include both Main and partial view

Index.cshtml looks like:

```
@model WebApi.Models.mvcempmodel
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<body>    
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div>This is my Index.cshtml</div>
        @Html.Partial("ViewCheckBox", Model)        
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#NSupport").change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    alert("inside");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Partial cshtml looks like:

```
@model WebApi.Models.mvcempmodel


@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NSupport, new { data_toggle = "toggle", data_width = "100", data_on = "yes", data_off = "No", data_offstyle = "info" })
```

Comment: Its not working and not showing any error. This checkbox is in partial view

Comment: @Doc don't put your javascript inside the partial view. put the script on the parent view. That's why it is not working.

Comment: @ tontonsevilla it is in partial view

Comment: @Doc check this [Is it OK to put JavaScript in Partial Views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11099593/8795884).

Comment: @ tontonsevilla but all the remaining scripts are running in this partial view even on of function for the same check box is also working if you check my edited post

Comment: I also tried in separate script file but still not working

Comment: @Doc - are you loading the partial view when the  main page load or is your partial view loaded later using Ajax?

Comment: loading with main page

Comment: @Doc - I tried to do exactly what you have described in the comments and I have updated my answer above. The above code is working perfectly fine, Can you refer to the above code and verify with yours?

Comment: @Jeethendra thanks for your support but it seems like some issue that is preventing me to call on change event "freedomn-m"  suggestions might be help me out. let me check  :(